# Making an array in a class with object count of another class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop

What if we have two classes Movie and Movies in c++. Movie class has all the attributes and methods associated with the class. Whereas Movies class is the collection of Movie objects. So what I understood from this is that we have to make an array in movies class which has all the objects of movie class but how can we write the code for movies class in that way?

Comment: *but how can we write the code for movies class?* You put characters one after another in the correct order just like any other program.  My recommendation is you consult your programming references and then make an attempt at solving the problem yourself. Ask questions about the attempt if necessary.

Comment: You also need to understand the fundamental concept of using classes. Take a look at
 https://www.quora.com/When-should-I-use-classes-in-C++

Answer (score 2):

Better to use a vector than an array

```
#include <vector>

class Movie
{
    ...
};

class Movies
{
public:
    ...
private:
    std::vector<Movie> data;
};
```

As for the rest of the class, that's really up to you. Think about what operations you want on a collection of movies, and code those. For instance you might want to know how many movies there are in your collection, you might want to add a movie to your collection, you might want to find a particular movie in your collection. Just think about what you want and write the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the amount of objects pre-hand (say you generate objects of `Movie` using rng in `main()` or your professor will create a random number of objects) then use a vector.

The other option is to count them in a constructor and return the count value via a function as the size of the array you want in `Movies`:

```cpp
class Movie 
{
    public:
    Movie() { ++count; }
    Movie(const Movie&) { ++count; }
    Movie() { --count; }

    static size_t movieCount()
    { return count; }

    static size_t count;
};
size_t Movie::count = 0;

class Movies : public Movie
{ 
  public:
  Movie array[movieCount()];
}
```